# Find the length of vector b (vectors)

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

Okay, this problem may be ridiculously easy, but I have been at it for a while, and I keep getting something different. It goes like this:

> Two vectors $a$ and $b$ in the plane. It is known that
>
> - The angle between $a$ and $b$ is 60 degrees.
> - $|a|=3$
> - $|a+b|=4$
>
> What is $|b|$?

I have tried drawing parallelograms, used the sine and cosine relations, but I keep getting something different. I hope someone can help me with this.

My attempt at solving the problem:

$|a+b|^2 = (a+b) \cdot (a+b)=|a| + 2\cdot |a| \cdot |b| \cdot cos(v) +|b|$

$4^2=3+2\cdot 3\cdot |b| \cdot cos(60)+ |b|$

$13=3\cdot|b|+|b|$

$13/4=|b|=3,25$

Comment: Well, what is $a\cdot  a$?  What is $(a+b)\cdot  (a+b)$? what do we know about $a\cdot b$?

Comment: Well, we don't really know anything about $a*b$? Or do we?

Comment: @Carl $a \cdot b = |a||b|\cos\theta$

Comment: And you have information on $a\cdot b$ from $(a+b)\cdot (a+b)$.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem but I don't think I'm right. Can you take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You know that $\lVert a+b\rVert^2=16$ and you also know that$$\lVert a+b\rVert^2=\lVert a\rVert^2+\lVert b\rVert^2+2\cos(60^\circ)\lVert a\rVert.\lVert b\rVert.$$

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand where that relation comes from?

Comment: @Carl, that's the [law of cosines.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)